# Como restringir el acceso a una pagina si tratan de ingresar por URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, seguridad

Tengo una pagina web en la cual quiero añadir una session la cual verifique que realice los pasos anteriores ya que en este momento yo puedo cambiar la url a diferentes archivos php que tengo y me muevo libremente por la pagina y lo que quiero es que me salte una pagina de error si el usuario realiza esta función. el usuario deberá seguir el recorrido normal de la paginas el cual sera pasar a la pagina 1,2,3,4,5,6 y no ingresar a la 1 y si me se el url de la 6 escribirla y saltarme todos los otros pasos. estuve intentando con una función pero no me resulto, espero puedan entender mi pregunta y ayudarme
Esta es la función que cree y que llamo desde las paginas pero aun asi puedo seguir saltándomelas.

```
<?php
function verificarPaso($pasoActual, $pasoAnterior) {
  session_start();

  // Si el paso anterior no se ha completado, redirige al usuario a la página anterior
  if (!isset($_SESSION['paso' . $pasoAnterior]) || !$_SESSION['paso' . $pasoAnterior]) {
    header("Location: pagina$pasoAnterior.php");
    exit();
  }

  // Marcar el paso actual como completado
  $_SESSION['paso' . $pasoActual] = true;
}
?>
```

```
<?php
//pagina1
session_start();
$_SESSION['paso1'] = true;
?>


<?php
//pagina2
include 'verificarPaso.php';

// Verificar si el usuario ha completado el paso 1 antes de permitirle acceder al paso 2
verificarPaso(2, 1);
?>


<?php
//pagina3
include 'verificarPaso.php';

// Verificar si el usuario ha completado el paso 1 antes de permitirle acceder al paso 2
verificarPaso(3, 2);

?>
```

etc...

Comment: el usuario esta registrado y exista un base de datos detras ? Si es así, controlalo desde el servidor guardando info de los pasos que ha echo.

Comment: Otra opción que quizás te sirva es el metodo: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] Echa un vistazo a este hilo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240145/how-to-use-serverhttp-referer-correctly-in-php

Comment: Usas formularios? quizás ahí puedas meter tu validación...

Comment: no, al final de proceso recién tengo un formulario, antes de eso son tarjetas con diferentes opciones que va seleccionando el usuario

Comment: Pues si no tiener un server para ir validando según tus intereses, puedes usar el LocalStorage, por ejemplo, para ir guardando y validando los pasos..